# What does "it rolls cargo" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/roll_1?q=roll

Maersk has been a proponent of migrating traditional ocean freight processes to its digital channel over the past year, a drive accelerated in June 2019 by the introduction of “Maersk Spot”, a digital product that penalizes shippers for container no-shows and Maersk if **it rolls cargo** booked online via the Spot channel.

Source: https://www.joc.com/maritime-news/container-lines/maersk-line/maersk-levy-manual-change-fees-september_20200722.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Roll" as used here is a shipping industry term. The Maersk Spot system penalizes the customer if they book space on a ship but do not bring the cargo container or containers in time or at all. The system also penalizes Maersk (the shipping company) if it fails to load a container that does arrive, because the ship is full.

> What is rolled cargo?
>
> Rolled cargo is cargo that could not be loaded onto the vessel it was
> scheduled to sail on, because that vessel ran out of capacity. Vessels
> run out of capacity because carriers overbook spots on vessels,
> similar to how passenger airlines overbook seats.

[What is rolled cargo?](https://www.flexport.com/glossary/rolled-cargo/)

Comment: Note that this is not a use of the word “roll” that a fluent native English speaker would be likely to know. It’s shipping industry-specific jargon.